# Fetch Order details between two dates in Mongodb from PHP

Tags: php, mongodb, php-mongodb

First of all I can find some questions asked related to this topic. But I could not able get through. This is more of a solution asked for my code.

I am sending two dates from Ajax with Javascript date.

```
var sd = new Date("2016-10-15T00:00:00.000Z");
var ed = new Date("2016-10-17T00:00:00.000Z");
$.ajax({
          type: "GET",
          url: "dashboard/load_revenue_chart",
          data: {type:"revenue",period:"no of days",start_date: sd.getTime(),end_date: ed.getTime()},
          dataType: 'json',
          success: function(data){
            line_chart(data);
        }
    });
```

Controller:

```
if (isset($_GET['period'])) {

        $collection = $this->selectCollection(); // public function for setting the collection.         
        $start = $_GET['start_date'];
        $end = $_GET['end_date'];
        print_r($_GET['start_date']); // Outputs : 1476489600000
        print_r($_GET['end_date']); // Outputs : 1476662400000

        $result = $collection->find(array("OrderedOn" => array('$gt' => $start, '$lt' => $end)));
        print_r($result);
}
```

Output:

> MongoCursor Object
>   (
>   )

Have tried with ISOString also. Not able to get the output. But when i try the same with Mongo Shell, I am able to get the result.

I dont know what i am missing. It will be a great help if you explain me how to get the result with PHP.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$dateRange = $collection->find(array("timeStamp" => array('$gt' => $start, '$lt' => end)));
where $start is the start date & $end is the end date
```

Comment: Tried the same. Not getting any result. in which format i have to give the start date and end date?

Answer (score 0):

When you save date in mongo DB database using php using gine mongo function.
new \MongoDB\BSON\UTCDateTime() then date format will be save on DB like this:

> updateTime :  ISODate("2020-06-02T07:09:57.099+0000")

When you want fetch all records between two dates. Example like current date and 60 day.
Back date using php then ex like this:

```
$milliseconds = round(microtime(true) * 1000);

$dt1 = date("Y-m-d", strtotime("-60 day"));
$dt2 = date("Y-m-d", strtotime("-1 day"));

$where = [ "updateTime" => array('$gte' => new MongoDB\BSON\UTCDateTime(strtotime("$dt1")* 1000), '$lte' => new MongoDB\BSON\UTCDateTime(strtotime("$dt2")* 1000))];

$fetchAllUser = new MongoDB\Driver\Query($where);
$fetchAllUser =  $connection->executeQuery($db.".collname", $fetchAllUser);
```